# Summing huge numbers

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, average

Here is the situation, I really don't know what is really going on when adding big number to each other to calculate all the average at the end.

Please correct me if there is a specific error to edit.

I have debugged and I'm just finding in data, my normal data in the following loop but it seems that the variable "somme"gives me sometines some random numbers and gives something totally wrong. The same for "moyenne"

Something else, all data are, or 0 or a positive number.
Somme gives sometimes a negative number!

```
#define Nb 230400
std::vector<std::array<double,480>> data(480);

    double somme=0;
    double moyenne=0;
    for (int i=0;i<480;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<480;j++)
            somme=somme+data[i][j];

    }
    moyenne=somme/Nb;
```

Comment: Seems like you're overflowing the `somme` variable. You can calculate `moyenne` directly with `moyenne=moyenne+data[i][j]/Nb;`.

Comment: Probably because your sum gets too large? Look into a bignum library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: And of course, the idiomatic way of writing this in C++11 would be `double moyenne = std::accumulate( data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0, []( double a, std::array<double, 480> const& b ) { return a + std::accumulate( b.begin(), b.end(), 0.0 ); } ) / (data.size() * 480);`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore (and others): if he's on a PC or a typical Unix system, overflow should result in infinity, not some negative number.  (But we need more information concerning his environment, and the constraints on values in `data`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze My environment is already state about in tags, as for values, in data, what do you mean by "constraints"?

Comment: @MelMed James Kanze asked this already, but what makes you so sure you have only >=0 values in the array and vector? (There is no automatic initialization to zeros.) It may also be useful to show the code you use to check the result.

Comment: @jogojapan If the values are in a `vector` (which is what he is showing), there is.

Comment: @JamesKanze Admitted, the vector does this. (But a standalone, default-initialized `std::array` would not.)

Comment: Let's be quite clear about this: on an Intel based PC, there is _no_ condition where adding two non-negative numbers can result in a negative number.  Ever.  (At least when using the FPU.  Can anyone confirm that this is still true with SSE2 instructions.)

Comment: @jogojapan Which is a good point.  vector will null its elements _if_ he constructs the vector with the actual dimensions from the start.  If he's used `push_back`, on the other hand, vector will only copy the `std::array` that it's given, which may not have been initialized.

Comment: By the way: somme is a float and you are deviding it by a int, `#define Nb 230400.0` would not require an implicit cast.

Comment: @urzeit `somme` is a `double`, not a `float`, and he's dividing it by a `double`: C++ doesn't do division of mixed types.

Comment: @James Kanze: The literal 320400 IS a int and it will be compile-time casted to double.

Comment: @urzeit The literal 320400 is an `int`, but that's not what will be divided.

Comment: @James Kanze: True, but at the level of source code there is a division by int that will be - as i noted - implicitly casted to float to do the actual computation. I don't think an division float/int or int/float does even exist.

Comment: @urzeit It doesn't exist on most architectures, which is why C++ doesn't support it.  C++ does support a lot of implicit conversions.  In this case, however, the "conversion" is done by the compiler, at compile time, and there is absolutely no difference whether he specifies `320400` or `320400.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, with the code you've given, there is no way you can get
negative results (at least with the IEEE floating point used on
PCs and the usual Unix machines); if you overflow, you will get
the special value `Inf` (but you cannot overflow if the data are
in the ranges you specify).  The results may be wrong, due to
rounding errors, but they will still have a lower bound of 0.

You haven't specified how you determined that the results were
negative, nor how you ensure that the input data is in range, so
I can only speculate; but the following are distinct
possibilities:

- You compiled with optimization turned on, and you are looking
  at the values with the debugger.  The debugger will often show
  wrong values (uninitialized memory) when looking at optimized
  code.
- You have undefined behavior (a pointer problem) elsewhere,
  which corrupts the memory you're looking at here.  99% of the
  time, this is the explination of otherwise unexplainable
  behavior, but I'm somewhat dubious here: provided there is
  nothing else in the code sequence you posted, and there are no
  other threads running, there are no pointers (at least that you
  manipulate) to misuse.
- You failed to properly initialize the data.  You might want to
  add an assert in the innermost loop, just to be sure:

  ```
      for ( int i = 0; i < 480; ++ i ) {
          for ( int j = 0; j < 480; ++ j ) {
              assert( data[i][j] >= 0.0 && data[i][j] < 200000.0 );
              somme += data[i][j];
          }
      }
  ```

For the rest, your algorithm isn't particularly accurate.  Some
quick tests (filling your data structure with random values in
the range `[0...2e5)`) show less than 15 digits accuracy in the
final result.  (Of course, this may be acceptable.  Most
physical data that you acquire won't have more than 3 or
4 digits accuracy anyway, and you may not be displaying more
than 6.  In which case...)

The accuracy issue is actually curious, and shows just how
tricky these things can be.  I used three functions for my
tests:

```
//  Basically what you did...
double
av1( std::vector<std::array<double, cols>> const& data )
{
    double somme = 0.0;
    for ( int i = 0; i != data.size(); ++ i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j != cols; ++j ) {
            somme += data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return somme / (data.size() * cols);
}

//  The natural way of writing it in C++11...
double
av2( std::vector<std::array<double, cols>> const& data )
{
    return std::accumulate( 
        data.begin(),
        data.end(),
        0.0,
        []( double a, std::array<double, cols> const& b ) {
            return a + std::accumulate( b.begin(), b.end(), 0.0 );
        } ) / (data.size() * cols);
}

//  Using the Kahan summation algorithm...
double
av3( std::vector<std::array<double, cols>> const& data )
{
    double somme = 0.0;
    double c = 0.0;
    for ( int i = 0; i != data.size(); ++ i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j != cols; ++j ) {
            double y = data[i][j] - c;
            double t = somme + y;
            c = (t - somme) - y;
            somme = t;
        }
    }
    return somme / (data.size() * cols);
}
```

(In all of the tests, `cols == 480` and `data.size() == 480`.)

The code was compiled using VC11, with option /O2.  The
interesting thing was that `av2` was systematically more
accurate than your code, usually down to the 17th digit (2 or
3 bits in the internal representation), where as 
`av1` was often off as much as 2 or 3 in the 15th digit (8 or
9 bits in the internal representation).  The reason for this is
that your code systematically collects into `xmm1`, accross all
`480*480` values, where as `av2` collects each row separately;
this results in less additions with a large difference of
magnitude.  (As `av1` approaches the end of the data, `somme`
approaches `2.3e10`, which is significantly larger than any of
the data elements.)  Using something like:

```
double
moyenne( std::vector<std::array<double, cols>> const& data )
{
    double outerSum = 0.0;
    for ( int i = 0; i != data.size(); ++ i ) {
        double innerSum = 0.0;
        for ( int j = 0; j != cols; ++ j ) {
            innerSum += data[i][j];
        }
        outerSum += innerSum;
    }
    return outerSum / (data.size() * cols);
}
```

should give results equivalent to `av2`.  (But if you need the
accuracy, you really should go with the Kahan summing
algorithm.)

(I'm tempted to add that if any of this surprises you, you
shouldn't be using floating point anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that a data overflow happened. The overflow changed the sign bit so it looks like a negative number.
Try "long double" instead of "double" if you're dealing with really big numbers.

Comment: They are really big for me, the range can be from 0 to 100K.

Comment: @MelMed 100K is not too large for double. You should check your data array to see if there is something wrong, i.e. not initialized or precision problems. If your data ranged widely in precision, check the answer of urzeit.

Comment: First, this answer describes the behavior of integral types, not floating point.  For floating point (at least on most modern machines), overflow returns a special value `Inf`.  Second, precision may be an issue, and you might want to look into the Kahan algorithm.  Once you get this working, however: given the code you've show, it is impossible for you to obtain a negative results unless some of the data is negative.  So there is something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @Manas Adding 100000.0 to 1e-40 is going to seriously loose accuracy.  (But it still won't cause a negative result.)

Comment: Yes this is my problem! Sometimes a negative result

Comment: @Manas But of course, `100000 * 230400` is still very, very far from overflowing a double (or even a float).

Comment: @Manas it's about 480*480 values between 0 and 100K, even 200K

Comment: @MelMed In which case, either negative values have crept into your data, or there are problems in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: @JamesKanze this is only what I have. But it seems that you would like to see 480*480 values in 480*480 lines? You are welcome lool

Comment: @MelMed So is that how you verified they are all >=0? Looking at them? I mean, you could have checked programmatically, right. And adding that program to the question for clarification would be really helpful.

Comment: @MelMed I agreed with JamesKanze. Better check your data, add a breakpoint and watch the values maybe. Or have you tried to divide every data[i][j] by Nb and add them together?

Comment: @MelMed Obviously, we don't want to manually look at the values.  In order to analyze your problem, however, we need to be able to reproduce it.  Where do the values come from?  How do they get into the vector<array>?  How can we easily simulate them?

Answer (score 0):

This may also be caused by floating point errors. The floating point error can be really large if you add numbers in different dimensions (such as `10e-10 + 10`) while the error is smaller if the dimensions are similar.

If all numbers are large, your code should work (if there is no overflow). If not, you may increase accuracy if you add the numbers sorted. Pseudocode:

```
array a;
sort(a);
foreach i in a:
    somme += i
somme /= count(a)
```

The reason is, that the smallest numbers summed up may be of a more similar dimension like the next bigger number. This way the error gets smaller.

To avoid overflows you may devide each i by count(a) instead of deviding the result. This should not change the accuracy if no overflow happens.

PS: If you sort the array descending or reverse the loop you can maximize your error!

Comment: Whether the numbers are large or not is irrelevant.  The important issue is that they all have more or less the same magnitude.  If so, the rounding errors f0r 230400 doubles shouldn't be too bad.  If they are, of course, I should use the Kahan algorithm for summing---sorting may help, but it's far from guaranteed.